# Soap enabler, maven Build Failure

Tags: android, maven, soap-extension

Trying to run a new sample project with soap enabler https://code.google.com/p/android-soap-enabler/
And i keep getting a build failed exception, I double checked the system variables and everything seems fine in my maven local repo.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Sample 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ Sample ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystem;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2317)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1762)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:661)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:366)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:165)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:609)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:565)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:551)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:865)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:790)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:278)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:210)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:986)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:982)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:44)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:134)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:259)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:251)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:459)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:97)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystem
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
        ... 57 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.827s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 25 12:39:32 IDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project Sample: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources failed: A required class was missing while executing com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6
.0:generate-sources: Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystem;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/jayway/maven/plugins/android/generation2/android-maven-plugin/3.6.0/android-maven-plugin-3.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/builder/0.4/builder-0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/sdklib/22.0/sdklib-22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.1/httpclient-4.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/httpcore-4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1/httpmime-4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/22.0/layoutlib-api-22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/dvlib/22.0/dvlib-22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.0/commons-compress-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/0.4/builder-test-api-0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/0.4/builder-model-0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/common/22.0/common-22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/13.0.1/guava-13.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/sdk-common/22.0/sdk-common-22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/22.0/ddmlib-22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/22.0/manifest-merger-22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.1.1/sisu-inject-bean-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.9.4/sisu-guice-2.9.4-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/emma/emma/2.1.5320/emma-2.1.5320.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.3/plexus-archiver-2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.6/plexus-io-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.10/plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/commons-jxpath/commons-jxpath/1.3/commons-jxpath-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.1/asm-4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.13.1/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/github/rtyley/android-screenshot-paparazzo/1.9/android-screenshot-paparazzo-1.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/madgag/animated-gif-lib/1.0/animated-gif-lib-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/shimita/.m2/repository/com/github/rtyley/android-screenshot-celebrity/1.8/android-screenshot-celebrity-1.8.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>fr.norsys.asoape.it:Sample:1.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystem
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound
```

The pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fr.norsys.asoape.it</groupId>
  <artifactId>SampleApp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>apk</packaging>
  <properties>
    <asoape.version>1.1</asoape.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fr.norsys.asoape</groupId>
      <artifactId>runtime-library</artifactId>
      <version>${asoape.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <version>1.6_r2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>fr.norsys.asoape</groupId>
        <artifactId>asoape-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${asoape.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate-soap-stub</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <definitionsDirectory>${project.basedir}/wsdl</definitionsDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <genDirectory>gen</genDirectory>
          <sdk>
            <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
            <platform>4</platform>
          </sdk>
          <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
          <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>alignApk</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>zipalign</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildcommand>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</buildcommand>
            <buildcommand>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</buildcommand>
            <buildcommand>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</buildcommand>
          </additionalBuildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK</classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>com.google.android:android</exclude>
            <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
            <exclude>org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient</exclude>
            <exclude>org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore</exclude>
            <exclude>commons-codec:commons-codec</exclude>
            <exclude>org.khronos:opengl-api</exclude>
            <exclude>xerces:xmlParserAPIs</exclude>
            <exclude>xpp3:xpp3</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It has something to do with maven version 3.1.0-alpha-1 . I had the same error building an Android maven project and I solved it by installing maven version 3.0.5 .

Comment: I still had the error using 3.1.0 final. Using 3.0.5 solved it. Thanks

Comment: Version 3.8.0 of the android-maven-plugin also solves the issue.

Comment: just in case `android-maven-plugin` is `3.6`, if it helps anyone!

Answer (score 35):

Move to version 3.8.0 of the android-maven-plugin, it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to maven 3.2.1 fixed the issue for me.

JDK 7.

Windows 7 64 bit.